# Is it possible to override the static styles within a Lit component based on an external property?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, lit

I'm trying to specify a theme as a property, and then override the `static styles` property on the Lit element.

This would be handy because then I could share an interface with my users such that they would have a type-safe way of composing custom themes of my web components for their own apps.

However, when I change the `static styles` property, Lit doesn't seem aware of the change, nothing actually happens. I've tried doing it in both the `constructor` and `connectedCallback` methods, but neither worked. In my real-world use case, it's slightly more complicated because I have a `BaseComponent` being inherited with its styles by other components, but let's leave it aside for this question, I guess.

Is this really possible? Or should I stick to using `styleMap`, `classMap` and [regular CSS custom properties](https://lit.dev/docs/components/styles/#customprops).

On the Lit's Discord server, another user mentioned that I might need to use [Constructable Stylesheets](https://web.dev/constructable-stylesheets/) — and it's apparently what Lit uses under the hood — but I'm not sure where to even start with that.

> You can take a look at this example on Lit's playground [here](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=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-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-SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ8L3A-YDtcbiAgfVxufVxuIn0seyJuYW1lIjoiaW5kZXguaHRtbCIsImNvbnRlbnQiOiI8IURPQ1RZUEUgaHRtbD5cbjxoZWFkPlxuICA8c2NyaXB0IHR5cGU9XCJtb2R1bGVcIiBzcmM9XCIuL2hlbGxvLXdvcmxkLmpzXCI-PC9zY3JpcHQ-XG48L2hlYWQ-XG48Ym9keT5cbiAgPGhlbGxvLXdvcmxkIGN1c3RvbS10aGVtZT0ne1wicHJpbWFyeVwiOiBcIm9yYW5nZVwifSc-PC9oZWxsby13b3JsZD5cbjwvYm9keT5cbiJ9LHsibmFtZSI6InBhY2thZ2UuanNvbiIsImNvbnRlbnQiOiJ7XG4gIFwiZGVwZW5kZW5jaWVzXCI6IHtcbiAgICBcImxpdFwiOiBcIl4yLjAuMFwiLFxuICAgIFwiQGxpdC9yZWFjdGl2ZS1lbGVtZW50XCI6IFwiXjEuMC4wXCIsXG4gICAgXCJsaXQtZWxlbWVudFwiOiBcIl4zLjAuMFwiLFxuICAgIFwibGl0LWh0bWxcIjogXCJeMi4wLjBcIlxuICB9XG59IiwiaGlkZGVuIjp0cnVlfV0).

I think part of the problem is that I just can't seem to change the stylesheet part of components (`static styles`) during runtime, only at compile (transpile) time.

Lit Component:

```js
import {html, css, unsafeCSS, LitElement} from 'lit';
import {customElement, property} from 'lit/decorators.js';

type Color = string;
interface CustomTheme {
  primary: Color;
}

const customTheme = {
  primary: "orange"
}
    
function themeToLitCss(theme: CustomTheme) {
  return css`
    p {
      color: ${unsafeCSS(theme.primary)}
    }
  `
}

@customElement('hello-world')
export class HelloWorld extends LitElement {
  static styles = [];

  @property({
  attribute: 'custom-theme',
  converter: (attrValue: string | undefined) =>
    attrValue ? JSON.parse(attrValue) : undefined,
  })
  customTheme?: CustomTheme;
  
  override connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    
    // Overriding the styles with an external theme specified by the user
    if (this.customTheme) HelloWorld.styles = [this.customTheme];
  }

  render() {
    return html`<p>Hello World</p>`;
  }
}
```

The HTML would look like this:

```html
<hello-world custom-theme='{"primary": "orange"}'></hello-world>
```

> I've also created [an issue](https://github.com/lit/lit/issues/3742) on Lit's Github repo.

Comment: The Lit gurus are on Discord.

Comment: Yeah, I did ask it there as well, previously in another thread, but now in a separate one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a [discussion with @justinfagnani](https://github.com/lit/lit/issues/3742) on Github, and later I came up with this workaround, based on his comments.

Here's the adapted example with it:

```js
import {html, css, unsafeCSS, LitElement} from 'lit';
import {customElement, property} from 'lit/decorators.js';

type Color = string;
interface CustomTheme {
  primary: Color;
}
    
function themeToLitCss(theme: CustomTheme) {
  return css`
     p {
       color: ${unsafeCSS(theme.primary)}
     }
  `
}

@customElement('hello-world')
export class HelloWorld extends LitElement {
  @property({
  attribute: 'custom-theme',
  converter: (attrValue: string | undefined) =>
    attrValue ? JSON.parse(attrValue) : undefined,
  })
  customTheme?: CustomTheme;

  render() {
    return html`
      <style>
        ${themeToLitCss(this.customTheme)}
      </style>
        
      <p>Hello World</p>
    `;
  }
}
```

It works on a per instance basis indeed:

```html
<hello-world custom-theme='{"primary": "orange"}'></hello-world>
<hello-world custom-theme='{"primary": "red"}'></hello-world>
```

> [Here is the link to it on Lit's playground](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=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-XG4gICAgYXR0clZhbHVlID8gSlNPTi5wYXJzZShhdHRyVmFsdWUpIDogdW5kZWZpbmVkLFxuICB9KVxuICBjdXN0b21UaGVtZT86IEN1c3RvbVRoZW1lO1xuXG4gIHJlbmRlcigpIHtcbiAgICByZXR1cm4gaHRtbGBcbiAgICAgIDxzdHlsZT5cbiAgICAgICAgJHt0aGVtZVRvTGl0Q3NzKHRoaXMuY3VzdG9tVGhlbWUpfVxuICAgICAgPC9zdHlsZT5cbiAgICAgICAgXG4gICAgICA8cD5IZWxsbyBXb3JsZDwvcD5cbiAgICBgO1xuICB9XG59XG4ifSx7Im5hbWUiOiJpbmRleC5odG1sIiwiY29udGVudCI6IjwhRE9DVFlQRSBodG1sPlxuPGhlYWQ-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).

I still do believe a more framework-native approach would make this a lot cleaner, but this will do for now.